# How to update pixelPosition of a custom infoWindows on Google Maps V3 after dragging?

Tags: dom, google-maps-api-3, infowindow, markers

I'm creating a new mashup on top of Google Maps. It's simple enough that I chose to use V3 to provide longer life span.

However, there's some special needs that Google Maps infoWindow doesn't provide.

I've positioned my custom infoWindow with marker.projectionContainer.pixelPosition. I get correct position after zooming, but dragging doesn't update markers pixelPosition. How can I get difference between markers old position and new after drag?

**or**

Should I use [OverlayView](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/v3/reference.html#OverlayView) instead of trying to hack position from DOM? I think Maps' own infoWindows are automatically updated/parked on panels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This answer assumes that by drag you mean dragging the marker and not dragging the map, let me know if that is not the case*

You should use the OverlayView and then you can use MVC techniques to bind to the marker's position property.

```
function MyOverlay(marker) {
  this.bindTo('position', marker);
}
MyOverlay.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView();

MyOverlay.prototype.position_changed = function() {
  this.draw();
};

MyOverLay.prototype.draw = function() {
  // This is where you recalculate the latLngToPixel stuff where latLng
  // is this.get('position');
};
```

You also need to implement the rest of the OverlayView interface: onAdd and onRemove.

Comment: Assumption was right and at the time I used a solution similar to one you provided. Thanks!